# ReactJS Error Button on click reference method not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS to create and render a table with the button as a last column:

```
                    var cols = [
                       { key: 'Id', label: 'Id'}  ,
                       { key: 'RevLock', label: 'RevLock' },
                       { key: 'Revision', label: 'Revision' },
                       { key: 'Name', label: 'Name' },
                       { key: 'ProjectNumber', label: 'Project Number' },
                       { key: 'Description', label: 'Description' },
                       { key: 'CreatedDate', label: 'Created Date' },
                       { key: 'Language', label: 'Language' }
                    ];


                    var Table = React.createClass({

                       getInitialState: function () {
                          return { data: [] };
                       },

                       componentDidMount: function () {
                          this.loadProjectsFromServer();
                       },

                       loadProjectsFromServer: function () {
                          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                          xhr.open('get', this.props.dataUrl, true);
                          xhr.onload = function () {
                             var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                             this.setState({ data: data });
                          }.bind(this);
                          xhr.send();
                       },

                       render: function () {
                          var headerComponents = this.generateHeaders(),
                          rowComponents = this.generateRows();

                          return (
                             <table>
                                <thead> {headerComponents} </thead>
                                <tbody> {rowComponents} </tbody>
                             </table>
                          );
                       },

                       generateHeaders: function () {
                          var cols = this.props.cols;

                          return cols.map(function (colData) {

                             return <th key={colData.key }>{colData.label}</th>
                          });
                       },

                       openElem: function ( ) {

                          console.log('Clicked ')
                       },

                       generateRows: function () {
                          var cols = this.props.cols;
                          data = this.state.data




                          return data.map(function (item) {

                             var cells = cols.map(function (colData, idx, arr) {
                                return (idx === arr.length -1)
                                           ? <td>{item[colData.key]}<DoorButton openItems={this.openElem }/></td> 
                                           : <td>{item[colData.key]}</td>;
                             });


                             return <tr key={item.Id }>{cells}</tr>;
                          });
                       },
                    });

                    var DoorButton = React.createClass({

                       handleClick: function (e) {

                          this.props.openItems();
                       },

                       render: function () {
                          return (
                             <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Open Doors</button>
                          );
                       }
                    });

                    ReactDOM.render(
                       <Table cols={cols}  dataUrl="/Project/GetProjects" />,
                       document.getElementById('projectTable')
                    );
```

This code works fine though when I click on the button um getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.openItems is not a function.

How may I trigger an onclick event for the button which was in the raw ?
[image]

Comment: where you assign the `openItems` prop to this component instance

Comment: <DoorButton openItems={this.openElem }/>

Comment: `<DoorButton openItems={this.openElem }/></td> ` do you define `this.openElem`?

Comment: @chenkehxx yep  openElem: function ( ) {

                          console.log('Clicked ')
                       }, its in the posted code as well

Comment: @Kalanamith yeah, but the context of `this` is wrong, the context of this is not table class, it's just your map function context. you should try to use arrow function.

Comment: `cols.map( (colData, idx, arr) => {
                                return (idx === arr.length -1)
                                           ? <td>{item[colData.key]}<DoorButton openItems={this.openElem }/></td> 
                                           : <td>{item[colData.key]}</td>;
                             })`

Comment: @chenkehxx this.props.openItems um still getting the error

Comment: @Kalanamith use `<DoorButton openItems={this.openElem.bind(this) }/>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it wont work Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: @Kalanamith yes because context of this is not proper. define `var self = this` above `return data.map` and then use self.openElem.bind(this);

Comment: @Kalanamith it should be bind(self) i think.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri its openItems={self.openElem } bind(self) didnt work out though , thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118517/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-kalanamith).